Where can I ask questions related to other cryptocurrencies?
Since questions about cryptocurrencies have become off-topic on Bitcoin Stackexchange, where I ask about other cryptocurrencies? I couldn't find a list of relevant Stackexchange sites.

Where can I ask cryptocurrency or blockchain questions?

I think we can forward this question to this community wiki on [meta.se]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363121/232061
